# Does PHP has a "Module" class

Tags: php, module

Sorry, I'm new to PHP. In the source code of PrestaShop, there are some modules which extends from Module. Such as:

```
class StatsLive extends Module
{
......
}
```

But I didn't find any class Module in the source code. Is it a native built-in class in PHP which it can extends it directly?
If YES, can you give me a document about it?
If NO, How can I find its definition?

Comment: Hmmmmm, I wonder if you Googled 'PHP Module Class'?

Comment: Simple answer, No it doesn't

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did googled 'PHP Module Class', the result is NO. But I didn't found any definitions in source code of PrestaShop 1.6 http://www.prestashop.com. "grep 'Module' * -rn" gives no definitions.

Comment: ["ModuleCore is the Module class"](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/373678-module-class-location-in-prestashop-16/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I don't understand why the following code works:class StatsLive extends Module. Did you mean the class StatsLive actually extends the class ModuleCore? How does PHP make it working?

Answer (score 0):

The Prestashop uses a prelaod mechanism to generate classes in memory at runtime. I didn't investigate much more, but the mechanism is in the file

```
prestashop/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php
```

It calls the code to evaluate a runtime class from a class in a php file in its function load()like the following:

```
eval($this->index[$classname.'Core']['type'].' '.$classname.' extends '.$classname.'Core {}');
```